# Android: ShareActionProvider: modify the list of share applications?

Tags: android

I'm using the ShareActionProvider in my app to share some text to the applications installed on the user's device.

I want to modify the list of applications that appear when the user clicks on the share icon.
for example I want to remove the "E-Mail" applications, SMS and only leave Facebook, Twitter and so on.

Is there a way to achieve this > any customizations that can be done to the list of share apps ?

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks Mark, your blog post clarifies the whole thing, I agree with you, it's just I'm exploring the possibilities